# Try to define a left join only with where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I try to find a particular SQL statement to replace an old SQL query. To summarize, I try to make a left join only with where conditions.
Here is my test environment:

```sql
create table Mst
(
    Id bigint not null primary key clustered,
    Firstname nvarchar(200) not null,
    Lastname nvarchar(200) not null
);
create table  Dtl
(
    Id bigint not null primary key clustered,
    MstId bigint not null references Mst(Id),
    DetailDescr nvarchar(500) not null
);
```

I fill the tables with some data:

```sql
declare @i as bigint = 0;
while @i < 999
begin
 insert into Mst values (@i, N'Name ' + Str(@i), N'Lastname ' + Str(@i));
 if (@i % 10 = 0)
    insert into Dtl values (@i*5+0, @i,  N'Description 1 for ' + Str(@i));
 if (@i % 2 = 0)
    insert into Dtl values (@i*5+1, @i,  N'Description 2 for ' + Str(@i));
 if (@i % 3 = 0)
    insert into Dtl values (@i*5+2, @i,  N'Description 3 for ' + Str(@i));
 set @i = @i + 1;
end;
```

The usual way for a left join is this:

```sql
select m.Id, m.Firstname, m.Lastname, d.DetailDescr
From Mst m left join Dtl d
on m.id = d.MstId;
```

This query returns 1266 rows. But in the old application, which I try to migrate, the select- and from-part is still predefined:

```sql
select m.Id, m.Firstname, m.Lastname, d.DetailDescr
From Mst m, Dtl d
```

The old where condition defines (in a separate software module) a no longer available LEFT JOIN:

```sql
where m.id *= d.MstId
```

So we have to migrate that approach and try to modify only the where condition if possible. For an inner join, the where condition is easy to define:

```sql
where m.id = d.MstId
```

But I need a left join, and I find no way with only modify the where condition. But to rewrite only the where-condition is the best way in that special application.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Stop using ANSI-89 syntax and "update" to ANSI-92 syntax and the problem doesn't exist. You're using 30 year old syntax and the `LEFT JOIN` format for that isn't supported anymore. It hasn't been for over a decade. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: This is not possible. `Mst m, Dtl d` gives you the cross join. Suppose Dtl is empty. A left join should return all rows from Mst.  A cross join will return 0 rows. There is no way you can apply a WHERE clause to that 0 rows to add back the missing rows

Comment: Is there a reason (besides time and co$t) the 'old application' cannot be modified (or replaced) so that the newer ansi syntax can be used?

Comment: Left join on is inner join on plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls.. What is the exact input & ouput to your later processing? You characterize the processing as adding a WHERE. But if the input is a cross join expression plus condition expression then you can still calculate the corresponding left join.

Comment: The application is 15 years old, and EOL is still planned. The source is unchanged for 8 years, and former programmers are not available. But we found with full-text search a source location where the ```WHERE``` is added as old ```LEFT OUTER``` style to ```SELECT FROM tab1, tab2``` string. So the most natural approach would be a correction of ```WHERE```. But I learned in the answer the reason why this is not possible. So now we have to modify the ```SELECT FROM``` and hope we found all places. The steps now are clear but more time-consuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once upon a time, SQL did not support outer join syntax.  It was an ancient world, where telephones were connected by wires to walls, where counties in Europe each had their own currencies, and most Americans watched one of three or four major networks on television.

At that time, Microsoft did not even have a real database.  But Sybase offered an outer join operator in the `WHERE` clause, `*=`, which Microsoft eventually adapted into SQL Server.  Microsoft SQL Server supported this through SQL Server 2008.  **Hence, no supported version of SQL Server supports outer joins in the `WHERE` clause.**

Happily a much better standard syntax now exists (lest we be despondent and think that things do not get better over time).  The "comma operator" in the `FROM` clause is relegated to its original definition -- a `CROSS JOIN`.  The `CROSS JOIN` filters out non-matches.  For instance, if `Dtl` has no rows, then `CROSS JOIN` returns no rows.

That is, there is no way to do what you want generically in the `WHERE` clause.  There are queries that can replicate an outer `JOIN`, but they require much more surgery to the query.  But there is a good alternative, which is to write your queries with the correct, modern syntax.